# Parse XHTML with Python 3.2

Tags: parsing, xhtml, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a malformed XHTML page in Python. I just want to get a few tags of the same type from it, but it seems impossible. Normal XHTML parsers doesn't like the malformedness, and BeautifulSoup won't work because of syntax errors in its code. What would be the best way to parse malformed XHTML and get the content of a couple of tags of the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! "Unfortunately" I solved it myself by using [this](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html?highlight=xhtml%20parser) parser and setting `html.parser.HTMLParser(strict=False)`. That made it read malformed XHTML quite well.

Comment: Keep in mind that strict=False is the default value, it's deprecated since Python 3.3 and it will be removed in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

"Normal" parsers? [lxml](http://lxml.de/) usually deals fine with malformed html, although it's quite "normal". :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pyquery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)

I'm not sure how much malformed your XHTML is, but it's worth a try.